# Third party man pages in touch bar

Tags: terminal, touch-bar, command-line

The yellow man feature of the touch bar does not seem to use `manpath`,
for example /opt/homebrew/share/man/ is ignored. How do you configure this?

Comment: Does `man` in Terminal find manpages from Homebrew?

Comment: It does work in terminal as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `MANPATH` entry to `/private/etc/man.conf` as follows:

```
MANPATH /opt/homebrew/share/man
```

This will direct `man` to include the specified path directory in the search path (from `man man`):

> If you don't specify an explicit path list with -M or [the] MANPATH [environment variable], man develops its own path list based on the contents of the  configuration
> file  `/private/etc/man.conf`. The  MANPATH statements in the configuration file identify particular directories to include in the search path.

If have tested it in Big Sur and it works.

**Why doesn't `man` honor the MANPATH environment variable in this case?** When you look for a man page by pressing the "Open man Page for Selection" option in the Touch Bar, a process like the following is executed:

```
login -pfq <username> /usr/bin/man -P ul <command>
```

where:

- `username` is your username
- `command` is the command whose man page you want to display

`login` starts `man` directly, and it is not aware of the value of the `MANPATH` variable.